# Dynamically set the view width using constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am new to ConstraintLayout, Below is my xml file in this I am trying to achieve my Textview width dynamically. If my @+id/btn1 visibility is gone then TextView (@+id/tv1) should expand to full width. Please suggest what approach I should use to solve this problem with in the same way.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_gap"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First thing first, if you have a min SDK lower than 17, you can now shift to using only start and end attribute and don’t repeat yourself for right and left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv_cur_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RS"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Payment Mode"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the screenshot,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FE9J.png) how it's looks now

Required UI[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxoSs.png)

Comment: Remove the guideline and set their constraints to each other.

Comment: I would rather use LinearLayout and set weight attribute to components

Comment: @TheWanderer, I have to divide the screen width equally. Also there are many other views related to each other.

Comment: You can use `0dp` for the width (`match_constraint`) which should balance them evenly.

Comment: @AdamOstrožlík I am not sure how to achieve this via ConstraintLayout (for now). But using a linear layout instead of ConstraintLayout is not a good strategy. As later is much efficient

Comment: @TheWanderer, I did not get you. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @AdamOstrožlík, I want to use constraint layout. Divide the screen in equal part just like layout_weight = 1 in Linearlayout and Expand view once the other view visibility Gone.

Answer (score 0):

> Remove textview endconstraint and connect to button & make horizontal chain between button & textview then textview takes fullwdith when button view is gone.

Try this

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="First thing first, if you have a min SDK lower than 17, you can now shift to using only start and end attribute and don’t repeat yourself for right and left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tv_cur_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RS"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Payment Mode"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This will work only if I have two view in horizontal layout. What if I have 3 view in a row. 2 view should display without any weight and 3rd should occupy the 2nd half of screen. I have added a screenshot in question

Comment: Yes it will work only on two views if more than two views you will acheive using linear layouts with horizontal orientation.